# Change specific node shape with graphviz python

Tags: python, nodes, graphviz

I am currently trying to generate a graph, but I have one condition on that graph and that is that nodes with only outgoing arrows should be ellipses, the rest should have a box shape, this is what I have:

[image: Here is the image ter illustration but every run generates something else]

So in this case I want: 'Place Order-Importance shift-I-Obiect Typc--Customers' and 'Place Order--Quantity shift-1--Object Type--Orders' to be ellipses. The rest should be boxes.

I have tried multiple things including creating a list of specific nodes that should be that an ellipse shape, however it seems that one of the shape commands might be overruling an other one. Does anyone know how I can have my desired output?

Some info about the code:

I make a list called differences with the nodes that should have an ellips shape, the rest should be box shape.

The model object is an object that contains all the edges but comes from another previously build code which I would rather not change since I think it should be possible to it here.

An edge object of model contains a 'source' node and a 'target' node.

I hope this is clear enough.

The specific code (snippet) is here:

```
from graphviz import Digraph

 g = Digraph('G', filename='./output/model_' + str(mi), format='png')
 # nxg = nx.DiGraph()
 g.graph_attr.update(rankdir='BT')

 g.attr('node', shape='box')
 sources= list()
 targets = list()
 PossibleModel.MAX_DEPTH = 3

 """Let us first see what the possible inputs are"""
 for edge in model.get_edges():
    sources.append(str(edge.source))
    targets.append(str(edge.target))
    
 difference = list(set(sources) - set(targets))
 print('difference',difference)

 for edge in model.get_edges():
   edge_contained = ''
     for rule in br_rules:
         if str(edge.source) in rule or str(edge.target) in rule:
            edge_contained += rule + '\n'
     if edge_contained == '':
        g.attr('edge', color='red')
        g.edge(str(edge.source), str(edge.target),label=str(edge.weight))
        if str(edge.source) in difference:
            g.attr('node',attrs=str(edge.source),shape='ellipse')
        else:
            g.attr('node',attrs=str(edge.source), shape='box')
        g.attr('node',attrs=str(edge.target))
        
     else:
        g.attr('edge', color='blue')
        #str(round(edge.correlation, 2)))
        g.edge(str(edge.source), str(edge.target), label=edge_contained)
        if str(edge.source) in difference:
            g.attr('node',attrs=str(edge.source),shape='ellipse')
        else:
            g.attr('node',attrs=str(edge.source), shape='box')
        g.attr('node',attrs=str(edge.target), shape='box')
```

The Dot file code is here:

```
digraph G {
graph [rankdir=BT]
node [shape=box]
edge [color=red]
"Place Order--Quantity_shift-1--Object_Type--Orders" -> "Determine shipping method--Shipping Method_shift-1--Object_Type--Orders" [label=100]
node [attrs="Place Order--Quantity_shift-1--Object_Type--Orders" shape=ellipse]
node [attrs="Determine shipping method--Shipping Method_shift-1--Object_Type--Orders"]
edge [color=red]
"Place Order--Importance_shift-1--Object_Type--Customers" -> "Determine shipping method--Shipping Method_shift-1--Object_Type--Orders" [label=100]
node [attrs="Place Order--Importance_shift-1--Object_Type--Customers" shape=ellipse]
node [attrs="Determine shipping method--Shipping Method_shift-1--Object_Type--Orders"]
edge [color=red]
"Calculate Order Value--Order Value_shift-1--Object_Type--Orders" -> "Determine shipping method--Shipping Method_shift-1--Object_Type--Orders" [label=100]
node [attrs="Determine shipping method--Shipping Method_shift-1--Object_Type--Orders"]
edge [color=red]
"Place Order--Quantity_shift-1--Object_Type--Orders" -> "Calculate Order Value--Order Value_shift-1--Object_Type--Orders" [label=100]
node [attrs="Place Order--Quantity_shift-1--Object_Type--Orders" shape=ellipse]
node [attrs="Calculate Order Value--Order Value_shift-1--Object_Type--Orders"]}'
```

Comment: Can you share the dot file of your image, looks like you already tried to do with `shape='ellips'` but this apparently doesn't work in your python code. Bij looking at the generated dot file you might see what might be wrong.

Comment: please find in the original question my dot file:

Comment: Should that be "ellipse"? With an 'e' at the end?

Comment: You are right but it still doesn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: I copied your DOT file code, added the missing curly brace at the end and ran it through `dot`. I can see two ellipses. Works for me.

Comment: Well yes I have two ellipses, but they are wrong because I should have 'Place Order-Importance shift-I-Obiect Typc--Customers' and 'Place Order--Quantity shift-1--Object Type--Orders' to be ellipses whilst here I get 'Calculate Order Value--Order Value_shift-1--Object_Type--Orders' and 'Place Order--Quantity shift-1--Object Type--Orders' to be ellipses. So that should change :) Only nodes that only have outgoing edges and no incoming should be ellipses.

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing what's in `edge.source` and `edge.target`, respectively. Maybe you should print out those two as well.

Comment: The edge.source and edge.target contain basically a string object with the label of the nodes e.g.  Place Order--Quantity_shift-1--Object_Type--Orders. I hope this is clear enough?

Comment: I think I found it: I just had to use that differences list after the creation of my graph and add the following:                                                                                        for node in difference:
        print(node)
        g.node(node,shape='ellipse')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using the **gvpr** language (http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf).  **gvpr** comes with the Graphviz package so it should already be present on your computer.
As a one-liner:
`gvpr -c 'N{if ($.indegree==0)$.shape="ellipse";else $.shape="box";}' yourfile.gv`
What it does:

- for each node

  - if there are 0 incoming edges (**indegree**) - set **shape** to *ellipse*
  - else set **shape** to *box*